# Which Python module to use to access the Proxy setting of Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, proxy

I am new to Python and would like to write a script to change Windows proxy settings based on the network I am connected to. Is there any existing python module I can use? Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
Sethu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`winreg`](http://docs.python.org/library/_winreg.html) and query the settings directly from [the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961).

```
 [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
 Settings] "MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001 
 "ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
 "ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
 "ProxyServer"="http://ProxyServername:80" 
 "ProxyOverride"="<local>"
```

For example, something like:

```
import _winreg

def getProxy():
    proxy = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings")
    server, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(proxy, "ProxyServer")
    enabled, type = _winreg.QueryValueEx(proxy, "ProxyEnable")
    if enabled:
        return server
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you set the HTTP_PROXY environment variable in Windows (either manually or within your program) for your application before sending the request? That should take care that any request you send it via urllib2 goes via Proxy.